# Will combat damage trigger fight abilities?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I've seen questions about if fighting damage is combat damage, but I don't think this is the same thing. The other questions I saw were asking if fight damage will trigger combat abilities. They say they're separate from each other, and nothing in the official rules say anything about my dilemma.

My question involves a [Foe-Razer Regent](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394572). When it's played, it will fight target creature, like [Savage Punch](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386652). Because it's fighting, it triggers its second ability to give it two +1/+1 counters at the next end step.

So my question is, will creatures attacking during the combat step trigger the Foe-Razer Regent's second ability? Or will it only be things like Savage Punch, where it says fight.

Comment: This is the other way around from the other question, asking whether combat counts as fighting instead of asking whether fighting counts as combat. But the answer's the same: they're two separate things. Fighting isn't combat and combat isn't fighting.

Comment: If they're entirely separate from each other, then neither one counts as the other. I'm not sure why you say that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I've gone ahead and answered, but I think the proposed duplicate does make it pretty clear that they don't interact.

Answer (score 3):

No, combat damage does not count as fighting, and will not trigger an ability that says "whenever a creature you control fights."

"Fight" is defined in the official rules. The text of it doesn't matter; all that matters is that it's a defined thing, and that it doesn't tie itself to combat in any way, so only something that actually says "fight" is a "fight".

Similarly, the entire combat procedure is spelled out in the rules. Nowhere in it does it mention "fight", so it *definitely* does not have any interaction with fight. (In fact, the only section of the rules that mentions fight is the section defining it, plus the summary of that definition in the glossary.)